# 2 teams with equal players and powers

Tags: c#, sql, algorithm, model-view-controller

I have Sql database which have there 10 Players and each player has power from 1 to 10. These are my player and team  classes

```
public partial class Team
{
    public int TeamId { get; set; }
    public string TeamName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> TeamPlayers { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> TeamPower { get; set; }
}

public partial class Player
{
    public int PlayerId { get; set; }        
    public Nullable<int> PlayerPower { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to create 2 team. In Each team should be 5 player. Players are chosen randomly from SQL databases and each team should be in balanced power. How can I select players from SQL and create 2 team in balanced power.
Thanks beforehand

Comment: What have you tried so far? how did it not work? what specifically are you having issues with?

Comment: Maybe this algortihm will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15213195/algorithm-attempting-to-balance-out-team-skill-levels-while-having-a-equal-am

Answer (score 1):

Add the a List of Players to the 2 Teams:

```
public partial class Team
{
    public int TeamId { get; set; }
    public string TeamName { get; set; }
    public List<Player> TeamPlayers { get; set; }  //<-- have "team players"
    //public Nullable<int> TeamPower { get; set; } //Dont need this if teams are supposed to have equal powers.
}

public partial class Player
{
    public int PlayerId { get; set; }        
    public Nullable<int> PlayerPower { get; set; }
}
```

To chose players randomly and balance powers you would do that in SQL if that's how you are populating the 2 Teams. It going to be a case of tallying up the powers and keep on swapping players to different teams until each teams power is the same. I'll leave this as an exercise for you, use this as inspiration: [Algorithm - Attempting to balance out team skill levels, while having a equal amount of players](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15213195/algorithm-attempting-to-balance-out-team-skill-levels-while-having-a-equal-am)